# How to use .after() with .grid() in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

`self.root.after(1000, self.label4.grid(row = 1, column = 0))`

```
self.label3.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
self.label4 = Label(self.frame2, text = "")
```

```
self.saveButton = Button(self.frame2, text = "Save")
self.saveButton.grid(row = 20, column = 0)
```

I am using this line of code to display a Label after 1 second on a frame in tkinter. It has worked with .pack but not with .grid. I want a save button to appear underneath the label but the label to appear above it, hence why I am using the grid system. Here is what I'm getting:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Put those labels in another frame which is put above the button.  Then call `.grid(...)` without `row` option on those labels will put new label in new row.